# Is there a way for me to retrieve the error codes from Kafka when my producer fails to publish a message successfully?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is there a way for me to retrieve the error codes https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_error_acodes from Kafka when my producer fails to publish a message successfully?

kindly please provide same POC for retriving error codes in java

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can register callbacks to the producer, for success as well as failure. Please see the below code:

```
public ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> sendMessage(String topicName, V message) {
    log.info("sending message :{} to topic {} ", message, topicName);
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);
    addCallback(message, future);
    return future;
}

private void addCallback(V message, ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> future) {
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<K, V>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<K, V> result) {
            //this is a callback for success. 
            // use result to know various attributes like offset can be known
            // using result.getRecordMetadata().offset(), etc.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            
            //use ex to know the exception that occurred while
            //publishing a message
        }
    });
}
```